# 4x4 grid with reveal when hover over cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to understand how to build something similar to this page https://addons.heroku.com/ , specifically the 4x4 'Data Stores' grid which displays the description when you hover over each of the icons, and then redirects to another page when you click on it. Rather than using images like they have, I'd simply like to just have a coloured cell with some text (and more detailed text revealed when hovering). Viewing source on that page hasn't helped me to understand what's going on, it's beyond my level of understanding.

Could someone describe how to build what I describe? I understand this is a basic level question, but that's the level I find myself at!

Comment: could be done using only CSS pseudo class :hover

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: If you don't know how to read the source code to figure out how to do this, how is us explaining how it works going to help you complete this task? Stackoverflow isn't for having answers handed to you, if you're not educated in HTML/CSS then you should start brushing up your skills, this isn't all that hard to do, but if you don't know what you're doing then it's going to take you forever to setup properly.

Comment: @Mike Everyone learns differently - a working example can go a long way sometimes. I'm not advocating that OP not RTFM but sometimes a bit of patience can be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, just want him to understand that this isn't really all that difficult, and he's obviously going to need to read up on HTML/CSS/Javascript basics, because that knowledge will get him further than just going to SO for answers all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to hide and show the elements that you want. You can use transitions to slide one div in and another out.

I've begun an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/443ub/1/

All of this uses 
`:hover`

In order to get the `<div>` to align horizontally you need to specify the display mode as inline block.

`display: inline-block`

You can see this used on the "square" class here: http://jsfiddle.net/443ub/3/

Comment: thank you for the response! One thing I don't understand is how to get the 4x4 grid. When I try each cell goes under the previous one instead of beside it.

Comment: @OP Did the updated fiddle provide something that would help you?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand why the 3rd grid has gone onto the 2nd line?

Comment: I've added a `<br />` tag to make the 3rd one go onto the second line. You could repeat the `<div>s` as many times as you want on a row then use a `<br />` to move to the next line

Answer (score 1):

If you want it basic (without the fancy text animation) you can just use CSS.

This code should give you some idea. HTML:

```
<div id="box">
  <div id="title">Title</div>
  <div id="description">Some more text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box{
  //set height/width and other stuff here
}

#title{
  display:block;
  //other css for font size/colour etc...
}

#description{
  display:none;
  //other css for font size/colour etc...
}

#box:hover #title{
  display:none;
}

#box:hover #description{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This have been done with CSS and Transitions.
You can animate properties like opacity and visiblity (plus some more) under certain circumstances.

In the case of the page you showed, there is a list of items.

just like this:

```
<ul>
<li><span>Here is some text</span>
<span class="description">I'am hidden as default and show on Hover</span></li>
<li><span>Here is some more text</span>
<span class="description">Hi</span></li>
</ul>
```

You can now define some CSS to make the defaultly hidden text visibile, as long as you hover over the list item. Like this:

```
ul li
{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
ul li .description
{
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top: 30px;
   transition-property: all;    
   transition-duration: 1s;
}

ul li:Hover .description
{
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/42VQa/

you can define, what you want to animate with the transition-property option.

Comment: Thank you, that looks easy, but how to get the 4x4 grid structure?

Comment: I would always recomment to use a grid system for that, my favourite is "foundation by zurb" (foundation.zurb.com) or you could create a litte grid your self. here is a little example, but that may do not works with every browser: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/aqBHq/ but you get the idea

Comment: Thank you! width: 25%; so easy when you know how. :-)

Comment: you are welcome. But you should be carefull with the example, because it does not clean it's floating and is not rock solid.